# IdentityServer4: MissingMethodException: Method not found: Int64 IdentityModel.EpochTimeExtensions.ToEpochTime<System.DateTimeOffset>

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

Hi i´m working on a identityserver4 and a spa client (angular) solution. So far it worked great, but after i added a new dependency IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation with minimal changes on the client side. i get the following error message in the spa browser at the call of sts/connect/authorize?.....:
MissingMethodException: Method not found: Int64 IdentityModel.EpochTimeExtensions.ToEpochTime(System.DateTimeOffset). (the error message is also shown at the console of the identityServer)

that´s the complete error message:

```
IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService+<CreateIdentityTokenAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.CreateIdentityTokenAsync(TokenCreationRequest request)
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator+<CreateImplicitFlowResponseAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator+<CreateResponseAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointBase+<ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint+<ProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I looking for update versions of the used dependencys but there are no one.
used Nuget packages: IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity ver. 2.0.0, IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation ver. 2.3.0, Identity.Dapper.MySQL ver. 0.7.0

Have someone a idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you update to the latest IdentityServer package (right now 2.1).

It appears this is a transitive dependency in your case (from the AspNetIdentity package). Just add IdentityServer4 explicitly